# seaborn uneven spacing between x ticks

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm plotting a seaborn plot, for example:

```
sns.pointplot (x=[1,2,3,10], y=[2,3,4,5])
```

How can I make the X ticks to have spcaing that represents their values? 10 should be further apart but the spacing is equal.

```
ax.xaxis.set_ticks([1,2,3,10]) does not work
```

Comment: `sns.lineplot(x=[1,2,3,10], y=[2,3,4,5], marker='o')`

Comment: Thanks! 2 follow up questions:
- How can I do it for pointplot?
- any way to delete ticks withput value?

Comment: `sns.pointplot` always makes categorical ticks, for numerical ticks you need `sns.lineplot`. With `ax = sns.lineplot(...)` you can use `ax.set_xticks([1,2,3,10])` to only enable some of the ticks. `sns.lineplot` also has options to only show points.